# Doing 2 things in background with asynctask

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, android-asynctask

I want create splash screen. In one hand, i retrieve informations from server by webservice dans in the other hand, my splash screen has a progresswheel (https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel).

The thing is my wheel is blocked during my Webservice is eecuting in an asynctask.

I tried to executeOnExecutor() on my asynctask for the wheel but it does not work.

There is my async task for the wheel :

```
private class LogoTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            pw = (ProgressWheel) findViewById(R.id.pw_spinner);
            pw.spin();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

My asynctask for Webservice is a classic one (get infos from database, parse in JSON and send to application. It works fine. 
I use **task.get()** to get my informations. I heard this function force code to wait the end of the Asynctask to continue. May be is this ?

I just want my progressWheel spin during my WebService retrieve informations.

How can i do that ?

**EDIT :**
Can i have 2 differents asynctask for that ? One for my networks operations and the other for spin ? Is it possible ?

Comment: you have to do it the other way round.. contact the webservice in doInBackground and init the ProgressWheel in onCreate()

Comment: Yes you can have two asyntask

Comment: Can you show an example ? I tried but it does not work. My wheel is blocked during my WebService is active :/

Comment: I have edited my code and downloaded images from internet so its working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your asynctask is wrong. You are accessing UI views in your background thread:

```
private class LogoTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pw = (ProgressWheel) findViewById(R.id.pw_spinner);
        pw.spin();//Ui elements should run in ui thread
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
       //network operations here
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //stop progress wheel or dismiss
    }
}
```

**Update** As per your request I tried that library. Here's the code that works for me:

```
public class CustomProgressBar extends Dialog {
Context context;
String message;
TextView textViewMessage;
ProgressWheel wheel;

public CustomProgressBar(Context context, String message) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    this.message = message;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_progress);
    textViewMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewMessage);
    wheel = (ProgressWheel) findViewById(R.id.progressWheel);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    wheel.spin();
    textViewMessage.setText(message);
}

}
```

Corresponding layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ProgressWheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/fragment_background"
android:padding="15dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progressWheel"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

<com.todddavies.components.progressbar.ProgressWheel
    android:id="@+id/progressWheel"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    ProgressWheel:barColor="#0097D6"
    ProgressWheel:barLength="40dp"
    ProgressWheel:barWidth="5dp"
    ProgressWheel:rimColor="@color/rim_body"
    ProgressWheel:rimWidth="1dp"
    ProgressWheel:spinSpeed="3dp" />
```

Instantating the class:

```
CustomProgressBar bar = new CustomProgressBar(yourContext,"Loading");
//onpreexecute
bar.show();
//doInBackground()
do network operations
//onPostExecute()
bar.dismiss()
```

I made it look like a progress dialog without titlebar.

Answer (score 0):

put the

```
            pw = (ProgressWheel) findViewById(R.id.pw_spinner);
            pw.spin();
```

in PreExecute Method

```
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pw = (ProgressWheel) findViewById(R.id.pw_spinner);
                pw.spin();
            }
```

and close it in onPostExecute method

```
   protected void onPostExecute(String abc) {
       // dismiss it
        }
```

Comment: It does not work. My wheel is blocked during the webservice :(

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i was using get() method ! And get() wait the end of AsyncTask to retun. so my wheel was blocked during the asynctask was running.

I have found a solution with BroadCast Intent. 
I send a broadcast on PostExecute and i have a receiver in my class who call the WebService. It work wery well ! :)